# Pandas get a specific column from one dataframe if the same column is in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

For the life of me I can not figure out how to implement the following solution:

Suppose I have a dataframe called **df1**

```
   ID  Name  Gender
   0   Bill    M
   1   Adam    M
   2   Kat     F
   1   Adam    M
```

Then I have another dataframe called **df2**

```
   ID  Name   Age
   5as   Sam  34
   1as   Adam 64
   2as   Kat  50
```

All I want to do is check if **ID** from **df1** is in **ID** in **df2**, if so grab the corresponding **Age** column and attache it to **df1**.

**Ideal Solution:**

```
   ID  Name  Gender  Age
   0   Bill    M
   1   Adam    M     64
   2   Kat     F     50
   1   Adam    M     64
```

I have implement the following solution which at first I thought it works but realized it was missing matching a lot of values at the end of df. Not sure if it is because of what I wrote or the size of my CSV which is large.

```
y_list = df2.ID.dropna().unique()

for x in df1.ID.unique():
   if x in y_list:
        df1.loc[df1.ID == x, 'Age'] = df2.Age
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you made an error writing your ID in df2?

Comment: Following up on Vishaka's comments, kindly check your  dataframe on the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do

```
df3 = df1.join(df2.set_index('ID'), on='ID', lsuffix='_left')
```

if you want to join on the 'ID' column.

If however you are looking to join on 'Name', you can change on='Name'.
An alternative option is to use merge,

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left')
```

Output

```
    ID  Name_x  Gender  Name_y  Age
0   0   Bill    M   NaN NaN
1   1   Adam    M   Adam    64.0
2   2   Kat F   Kat 50.0
3   1   Adam    M   Adam    64.0
```

Here's the output when using `caller.set_index('ID').join(other.set_index('ID'), lsuffix='_left')`

```
    Name_left   Gender  Name    Age
ID              
0   Bill    M   NaN NaN
1   Adam    M   Adam    64.0
1   Adam    M   Adam    64.0
2   Kat F   Kat 50.0
```

Comment: I think they want `on="Name"`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated both, the question said find 'ID' in another dataFrame...

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
name_age_dict = dict(zip(df2['Name'], df2['Age']))
df1['Age'] = df1['Name'].map(name_age_dict).fillna('')
```

Another method

```
df1['Age'] = df1['Name'].map(df2.set_index('Name')['Age']).fillna('')
```

**Output**

```
    ID  Name    Gender  Age
0   0   Bill    M   
1   1   Adam    M       64
2   2   Kat     F       50
3   1   Adam    M       64
```